# Xamarin Forms [iOS] - Webview inside ScrollView

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, wkwebview

I want to show Terms of Use page using WebView in ScrollView and detect when user scroll down to show accept button. But for some reason, after the html content, I have a lot of empty space that needs to be scrolled to reach the Accept button.

Can't attach images, so attached link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBk5b.jpg

CustomWebViewRenderer.cs
'''

```
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (NativeView != null)
        {
            var webView = (WKWebView)NativeView;

            webView.Opaque = false;
            webView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            webView.ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = false;

            var source = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');" +
                "meta.name = 'viewport';" +
                "meta.content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no';" +
                "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];" + "head.appendChild(meta);";

            var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(source), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, true);

            webView.Configuration.UserContentController.AddUserScript(script);
        }
        NavigationDelegate = new ExtendedUIWebViewDelegate(this);
    }
}

class ExtendedUIWebViewDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    CustomWebViewRenderer webViewRenderer;

    public ExtendedUIWebViewDelegate(CustomWebViewRenderer _webViewRenderer = null)
    {
        webViewRenderer = _webViewRenderer ?? new CustomWebViewRenderer();
    }

    public override async void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {
        try
        {
            var _webView = webViewRenderer.Element as CustomWebView;

            if (_webView != null)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                string result = await _webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("(function(){return document.body.scrollHeight;})()");
                _webView.HeightRequest = Convert.ToDouble(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error at ExtendedWebViewRenderer LoadingFinished: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

PageView

```
 <ScrollView x:Name="scrollView" Scrolled="ScrollViewScrolled" ios:ScrollView.ShouldDelayContentTouches="False">
   <Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <widgets:CustomWebView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="webViewTermsOfUse" Source="{Binding WebViewSource}"/>
   <widgets:CustomOutlineButton Grid.Row="1" x:Name="acceptTermsButton" Command="{Binding AcceptCommand}"
   Text="{x:Static utils:AppStringResources.Accept}" IsVisible="{Binding IsAcceptedVisible}"/>
    </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <p>
        <strong>
            THIS IS A TERMS OF USE EXAMPLE
        </strong>
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>
            PRIVACY NOTICE
        </strong>
    </p>

    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>

    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
    <p>
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>

    <p>
        <strong>
            Your choices and legal rights
        </strong>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you set a different background color on the webview, does that color the empty space also? If so, then the problem may be in your html content. OR its possible that webview doesn't actually understand how long its content is, in which case I don't know any solution other than to set a fixed grid row height, instead of auto.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I changed the background color and the color of the empty space also changed. I attached html, it is very simple html content

Comment: I tried all ways to get the exact height of content with the html data you provide , but the result always come incorrect(too big) , maybe as ToolmakerSteve mentioned , it's better to set a fixed value or `*` on row height.

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT The problem is that this page will be used by other applications and the length of the text is different for everyone

Comment: The workaround is to remove the outer ScrollView , and just set `*` on row height of Webview , so the Button will keep staying at bottom of screen .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT yes, but the reason for adding the scroll view was to control when the user scrolls down to show the accept button only then

Comment: hey @GeorgeEloyan did you manage to get this issue fixed?

Comment: hello @lawiluk, I don't remember how I fixed this problem, sorry)) I'm already working on another project